# Java interface- static method call

Tags: java, interface, static-methods

I got a problem I can't wrap my head around, and hope somebody can help me. Essentially, I have a hashed message and a signature. To verify it, I have to call a method in another class, with `Signing.verify(hash, signature)`. The interface, also used for other signatures, hence it cannot be changed, forbids static methods, but Java tells me either the method becomes static or I cannot verify it. 
I'm rather new to Java, but I hope somebody can help me. If the problem has already been encountered, I am sorry, but I have not found anything. 
Yours sincerely, and thank you for your time.

EDIT: 
Sorry-this is kind of complicated. The method, in the same package, looks like this- and is to be programmed later:

```
public class Signature implements SIG{
    public boolean verify(String message, String signature){
        //deadcode
        return true;
    }
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
public class SignatureTree implements Tree{
    public boolean verify(String message, String signature, String hash){
            byte[] publicKey=extractPK(signature);
            if(Signature.verify(message,signature)==false){
                   System.err.println("SIGNATURE VERIFICATION FAILED");
            }
            //some other stuff
    }
}
```

However, Eclipse is telling me to change the verify method in Signature to a static method-which is forbidden by the interface. Is that any more clear? Sorry-I'm more of a C programmer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Like... without any code present... What do you think we are, psychics??? If a method is non-static, then you need to call it via an instance of the class. That is as far as your question can be answered!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your question is currently quite unclear. You should read up on how to ask a good question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post a sample code so that we can help you.

Comment: So what's your interface? What is `Signing.verify(hash, signature)`'s role in your question? (Sorry, but that's the only code I find in your question, so I pay much attention to it!) Is `Signing` the interfae you are talking about? You want all subclasses of `Signing` to implement verify()? Or do you want to place the verify method in another class?

Comment: I want to place it in another class that verifies several signatures- I added some code above, I hope it helps. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question still not 100% clear, but from what I can understand, you should find another class that implements that interface.

Another option, long shot, probably won't work:

`if(new Signature().verify(message,signature) == false) { 
        // fail code here
}`

That code would assume Signature is not an interface, though.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, sorry (I tried though- if I have enough I will come back!)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read about Classes and their members in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

See, a class is something like a "template for objects", and you can instantiate an object of a certain class. For example, let's create a simple class:

```
class MyClass {
    public int var;

    public MyClass(int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public void incrementVar() {
        var = var + 1;
    }

    public static boolean isSmallerThanTen(int toTest) {
        return (toTest < 10);
    }
}
```

Now you can create objects that are instances of MyClass:

```
MyClass firstObject = MyClass(3);
MyClass secondObject = MyClass(10);
```

And you can call the `incrementVar()` method on a single object:

```
firstObject.incrementVar();
```

Now, `firstObject.var` is 4, but the second object has not been touched, `secondObject.var` is still 10.

But then, you have this method `isSmallerThanTen()` which is independent of the properties of a certain instance, you can call `MyClass.isSmallerThanTen(5)`. However, you can not call `MyClass.incrementVar()`, because `incrementVar()` is not static, it can only be called on an instance of `MyClass`, not on the class itself.

And that's exactly the problem you have, `Signature.verify()` is not static, which means you have to call it on an instance of `Signature`, not on the class itself.

So the following two solutions should both work, as they both instantiate an object of Signature:

```
if(new Signature().verify(message,signature) == false){
    ...
```

and

```
Signature sig = new Signature();
if(sig.verify(message, signature) == false) {
    ...
```

Btw: You can also write this as `if(!sig.verify(message, signature))`, the `!` is a logical "not", inverts the boolean value.